# How to validate file format in Laravel 5.4?

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5.4

I have a from in which users can upload an audio file. I want to use `validation` in `Laravel` to check file format because the file must be `m4a`.

I used following code for validation but it does not let any file to be uploaded even `m4a` files.

```
   $this->validate(request(),
            [   'title' => 'required',
                'body' => 'required',
                'category' => 'required',
                'audio' => 'mimetypes:audio/x-m4a'
            ],
            [   'title.required'    => 'title is missed',
                'body.required'     => 'body is missed',
                'category.required' => 'category is missed',
                'audio.mimetypes' => 'the file format must be m4a'
            ]);
```

Also I used `mimes:audio/x-m4a` and `mimes:audio/m4a` instead of `mimetypes:audio/x-m4a` but the problem already existed.

How can I validate it?

Comment: are you using Apache or Nginx as webserver?

Comment: @RDev I use Apache

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
  [
      'title' => 'required',
      'body' => 'required',
      'category' => 'required',
      'audio' => 'mimetypes:audio/mp4|mimes:m4a'
  ]
```

Comment: I tested your solution but it doesn't let any file even file with m4a extension to be uploaded. The mimetype of my test file is audio/x-m4a.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the official [Apache list of mime types](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk/docs/conf/mime.types)
the m4a file format have the audio/mp4 mime type associated.

First, look in your mime.conf and check if the line containing the audio/mp4 is commented, is so uncomment it and restart apache.

If it isn't present, you can add it in that file or in a .htaccess file with this directive: `AddType audio/mp4 .m4a .mp4`

If you are sure that the mime type of your file is x-m4a, add it to the .htaccess